# C++ expand variadic template arguments into a statement

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I'm currently playing around with template metaprogramming. I'm trying to make a finite state machine by using tmp. I know that there are several implementations in the web but I want to implement one by myself as an exercise.

I have a class called `Condition` which is the base class for the condition of a transition between two states. One implementation is the `AnyCondition` class:

```
template<class Input, Input comp, Input ... comps >
class AnyCondition: public Condition<Input>
{    
public:
    AnyCondition() {}

    bool operator()(const Input& input) const override
    {
        return input == comp || AnyCondition<Input, comps...>()(input);
    }

};
```

The thing here is, that the compiler will expand this recursivly, which results in a lot of recursive calls at runtime due to the `input` parameter. It should be more efficent, if the expanded code would be a statement like:

```
    bool operator()(const Input& input) const override
    {
        return input == comp1 || input == comp2 || input == comp3...
    }
```

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: You could use va_list to use loop through them and check each comp value?

Comment: I can't test it right now, but are you sure the compiler still uses recursive calls when compiled with optimisation on?

Comment: I don't think that *the compiler will expand this recursively*, but that it will expand that at compile time into a code as you desire. Have you tested that?

Comment: @Abhinav `va_list` is not template metaprogramming. The OP is looking for a compile time solution, with type safety.

Comment: Ah, okay thanks! Paul

Comment: @Walter Yeah that was what I meant. I actually didn't test how the compiler expands the code. That was just my interpretation of what I know about this topic so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++17 solution - [*fold expression*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold):

```
template <typename... Ts>
auto anyCondition(Ts... xs)
{
    return (xs || ...);
}
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/9qKUrGmS5o3I2orJ)

---

C++11 solution - `for_each_argument`:

```
template <typename TF, typename... Ts>
void for_each_argument(TF&& f, Ts&&... xs)
{
    (void)(int[]){(f(std::forward<Ts>(xs)), 0)...};
}

template <typename... Ts>
auto anyCondition(Ts... xs)
{
    bool acc = false;
    for_each_argument([&acc](bool x){ acc = acc || x; }, xs...);
    return acc;
}
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/5idf66ZaoVIjwufb)

I gave a talk about this snippet at CppCon 2015: 
[**CppCon 2015: Vittorio Romeo “`for_each_argument` explained and expanded"**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2l83JlqkzBk)

Comment: Thanks! And a great talk! Unforunatly VS 2017 RC doesn't support fold expressions right now so I had to use the C++11 solution. I had to make a little change to the `for_each_argument` function because your version isn't supportet by C++ compiler (according to error C4576). I replaced it with the initializer list that you suggested in your talk: `std::initializer_list<int>{(f(std::forward<Ts>(xs)), 0)... };`.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty much sure any decent compiler will optimize recursion into loop. But, if you are looking for some extra ways to expand variadic argument list of a single type, you can use simple `std::initializer_list` trick:

```
constexpr auto list = {comp, comps...};
```

Or, in your case:

```
inline bool operator()(const Input &input) const override {
    bool res = false;
    for (auto val : {comp, comps...})
        res |= val == input;
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is the good old comma trick

```
bool operator()(const Input& input) const override
{
  bool ret { input == comp };

  int  unusedA [] { ( ret |= (input == comps), 0 ) ... };

  (void)unusedA; // to avoid the unused warning

  return ret;
}
```

Comment: Care to expand on the comma trick? Is it just to introduce a sequence point?